# Make output spark table dynamic in R

Tags: r

all:

I'm new to R and wonder if anyone knows the solution to the issue below. I have a situation where I need to allow user to specify output names but I can't get it work. Thanks very much for your time!! Greatly appreicated.

```
class(tablex) ## tbl_spark table

#### this works, but mydata is static
grab <- function(data) {
  mydata<<-data %>% filter()
    }

grab(tablex)

#### this doesn't works
grab <- function(data, output) {
  output<<-data %>% filter()
}

grab(tablex,mydata)
```

Comment: grab <- function(data,grabcol,jointable,mycol,min) { data %>% filter(data_date %in% str) %>% select(party_id,data_date,{{grabcol}}) %>% rename({{mycol}}:={{grabcol}}) %>% inner_join({{jointable}},by='party_id') %>% filter({{mycol}}>=min) } test<-grab(tbl(sc,'common.scrattr_cvtg03'),finscore,customer,score_vtg3,300)

Comment: above works, as long as I don't put output inside function. After I implemented   eval(parse(text=temp)) I got errors unexpected error SPARK_LOCAL_IP.local.

Comment: If I use the function defined below `grab(data, "output_var")` I get `output_var <<- data %>% filter()` . To be honest: I don't understand the connection between your function stated in your comment and your desired function

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I appreciate it.

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer, if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

The user input determines the name of the variable?

So `output` is variable that contains the desired name as a string.

```r
grab <- function(data, output) {
  temp <- paste0(output, " <<- data %>% filter()")
  eval(parse(text=temp))
}
```